# VLC Stream with fallback video track

Tags: linux, command-line, vlc-media-player, streaming

I'm trying to use VLC for video-streaming, but I can't figure out how to add a fallback (external) video file.

For example, I have a playlist consisting of both .avi and .mp3 files, when VLC starts playing a .mp3 file I want it to add a video track from the external video file.

I'm running VLC in the Ubuntu command line; I tried `--input-slave` but that doesn't seem to add a video track to the output.

What do I need to add/change in my script to make this work, or are there other solutions(workarounds) available for this? (perhaps like a stream-wrapper).

Please note that I've tried using liquidsoap, but it doesn't work properly for me (ie: not an option).

This is what my script currently looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

#file="big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov"
file="Traced.mp3"
fallbackvideo="novideosignal.mkv"
logo="logo.png"
transparency=255 #0 = fully transparent, 255 = fully opaque
threads=3
vcodec=theo
acodec=vorb
width=1920
height=1080

vlc "$file" \
--input-slave="$fallbackvideo" --audio-track=0 \
--loop \
--width 1920 --height 1080 \
--sout "#transcode{sfilter=logo{file='$logo',x=5,y=5,transparency=$transparency},deinterlace,hq,threads=$threads,vcodec=$vcodec,acodec=$acodec,ab=192,channels=2,width=$width,height=$height}:std{access=shout,mux=ogg,dst=source:hackme@localhost:8000/shoutzor.ogg}" --sout-keep
```

Comment: Why don't you convert the mp3 to video by joining to the video track the mp3 as audio track?

Comment: because Id have to convert every single mp3 file into a video, which for this system means a ton of cpu usage and loads of HDD usage

Comment: For me on Windows this works perfectly well : `vlc video.mp4 --input-slave=audio.mp3 --audio-track=1`, and also the simpler `vlc audio.mp3 --input-slave=video.mp4`.

Comment: That spawns a 2nd window when I use input-slave while playing a video

Comment: It doesn't do that for me. Do you have the latest version? Also check in Preferences - [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5ight.jpg) are mine.

Comment: no the server doesnt but the client does (when playing a video and have input slave beeing a video too) yes I have the latest version

Comment: Your case is that of streaming (so why don't you use cvlc?), while I'm using vlc interactively, which works perfectly well. You should raise this question on the [vlc forums](https://forum.videolan.org/), because this looks like a bug in streaming.

Comment: I'll post it on the vlc forums too, that a great idea, didn't think of that. also, I can't really find anything about cvlc, isn't that just an alias for the vlc command? (there isn't a lot of in-depth command line documentation either)

Comment: cvlc : short [description](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/cvlc-console-vlc-player.html). See also mentioned in [Streaming HowTo/Command Line Examples](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/). Vlc is not overly documented - quite a few parameters in the examples are undocumented.

Comment: I have summarized our discussion below.

Answer (score 0):

For me on Windows, these work perfectly well :

```
vlc video.mp4 --input-slave=audio.mp3 --audio-track=1
vlc audio.mp3 --input-slave=video.mp4
```

However, your case is different because you are doing streaming,
while I'm using vlc interactively which works perfectly well.

My conclusion is that this is a bug in vlc streaming or a missing switch
not mentioned in the documentation (quite likely for an experimental feature).

As such, a better place to report it is on the [vlc forums](https://forum.videolan.org/).

If the developer(s) are listening, the problem might be repaired,
or some undocumented switch might be suggested
(there are quite a few of these).
The chances of finding one of the developers on our own forum are small.

Comment: Reporting it as a bug is probably a bad idea: the manual, https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/, explicitly states: *--input-slave=<string>     Input slave (experimental)
          This allows you to play from several inputs at the same time. This
          feature is experimental, not all formats are supported.*

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: Agreed. Being aggressive is a bad idea - better be polite and just ask for help. This being experimental, let the developers themselves decide whether this is a bug or missing documentation.